# Is there a way of anonymizing a post I made?

Tags: discussion

Short call: I made a post which is of no use for me or any one else but may even harm my rep, since its answers imply assumptions which I didn't try to express.

A flag with the please to delete it got denied.

So 1) Would there be a way to remove any linking from the post to my account?

If not, would deleting my account on this site just remove the linking but keep my name? Or would it become anonymized for any means?

Comment: You should be able to delete your own posts.  Deleted posts are only visible to high-rep users, and don't affect your rep.

Comment: But since it has answers I can't delete it anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your question is answered on [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86616/no-way-to-delete-an-answered-question).  However, a key statement there is:

> Moderators really shouldn't be removing decent content simply because the OP doesn't want it anymore.

I would say that simply worrying about your rep is likely not a compelling reason for your post to be deleted.  As described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki), by posting you have granted a license to display your post.

As described on both of those questions, you should contact StackExchange employees and/or site moderators if you want to have your post removed.  However, my advice is to not do this if you're just worried your question will lower your rep.  If you think your question is bad, edit it and make it better.  Over time, if you continue to post useful questions and answers, negative rep from that one question will not be major problem.  (As described on those questions, the main reason for deleting stuff that can't be deleted under normal site rules is if you post some sensitive information that needs to be removed to protect your privacy.)

Answer (score 1):

Only if you delete your account it will become anonymized. That is the only way, I've tried.

Comment: But thats for sure? and would be recreating the account and linking it again relink me to the post? Or would I keep staying in no connection to it?